# Count each element in array and displays which number occurs how many times?

Tags: c#

Write a function in c# that would return count of each element from an array?
For example
from this array[3,6,4,3,8,1,2,5,3,8] it should return/display the following results
“3” => 3 , “6” => 1, “4” => 1, “8” => 2, “1” => 1, “2” => 1, “5” => 1 (as three occurs 3 times in the
above array, 6 occurs one time & so on)

please help me. what is the logic of this program?

Comment: What do you mean by "what is the logic of this program"? You just wrote it. It counts how often a value appears in the array. In this case - as you wrote - the number 6 occurs only one time and the value 8 occurs twice. What is the question you have?

Comment: As a hint, try using a dictionary where the key is the number and the value is the count. Loop through the array and update the dictionary.

Comment: i want code for this program

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] array = { 3, 6, 4, 3, 8, 1, 2, 5, 3, 8 };

var query = ( from item in array
              group item by item into items
              select new { Key = items.Key, Count = items.Count() } );

foreach ( var item in query )
  Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " => " + item.Count);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Result:

```
3 => 3
6 => 1
4 => 1
8 => 2
1 => 1
2 => 1
5 => 1
```

Comment: Oliver Rogier i didn't get the result please display it properly, a complete program.